# Jasper reports causing CURSOR issues with SELECT statements

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jasper-reports, cursor

We are using Jasper reports with java for one of our reporting application and use ‘SELECT’ queries to fetch data and generate reports using Jasper reporting templates. They are a bunch of old queries, some are not tuned, their performance depends on the parameters they take. Ex-date ranges, categories, etc.

Lately, we have been experiencing weird cursor issues, the count of cursors the app is holding is going high, up to 900 at times, this is causing some serious space issues. We are manually closing them to temporarily overcome this issue. However, the issue is coming back again and again and has been a serious concern.

My understanding of the ‘SELECT’ statements is that they will implicitly use the CURSOR methodology, but make sure that once the operations are complete, they are closed. And we don’t have much control from the application side.

**Debugging / Troubleshooting the issue:**

- Database used - Oracle, Jasper - jasperreports-3.7.0, ODBC driver - 
  ojdbc14
- We ran the query though DBA and see no issues, again it's just a
  regular SELECT query and we are not explicitly creating any cursor.
- Changed the DB calls to a read-only state, didn’t work.
- Looks like Jasper server uses regular JDBC prepared statements - ODBC
  driver -  ojdbc14.
- No pagination used.

**Question**:

**We are out of leads on this issue, if someone can help us with this it would be great.**

**Edit**

SID =4385 has the following sql with count of open cursor

SQL_ID              COUNT(*)

---

- djuwsn5numsqv             2
- fw5920rbrun82            131
  0wk7fbztn67zh             1
- c29qmb59gggtv             1
- 6y1ajq8xaw294             1
- 9q3btvwzg96k6           487 ------->>>
- 3zzkryq60kua1             1
- anp287ycdrnp6             1
- 58tzy7dhpwnq4             1
- cfgz3kzhx53jy             1
- 0bxwy62tx9n2w             1
- cygg3t2hc6mr2           12
- 29s08m4n6xuwt             1

sql_id = 9q3btvwzg96k6 keeps opening the new cursors.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Is it cursors or sessions? If you are getting an ORA-xxxxx message it would help if you post it.

Comment: Turn on logging in jasper-reports to get more info log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query=debug

Comment: @PetterFriberg I did turn on the logging and monitored it for a couple of days now. Nothing strange, except that it shows resultsets being iterated more frequently. However, I am assuming that's ok. SInce the report is being used by various users.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett it is the open cursors. We are getting alerts since the open cursor count is reaching a threshold level.

Answer (score 1):

The local static cursors are closed for you.

you can see the max open cursors parameter as below:

```
show parameter open_cursor

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
open_cursors                         integer     300
```

Cursors opened within the inner block have obviously not been implicitly closed. Had they been closed, I would not have exceeded the maximum number of open cursors.

If cursor is already opened then Do Not close it , just use it.

In any case the quickest fix would be to

```
alter system set open_cursors = 1000 scope=both;
```

Comment: looks like it's taken care from the DB side. I am looking for a fix from the application side.